# Disable buttons during ajax requests

Tags: angular

I've seen many ways in jquery and Angular 1 on how to disable a submit button whilst an ajax request is being processed, but not for Angular 2.

So far on the template I have:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="requestSent">Submit</button>
```

and the following to toggle it's disabled state in the Typescript:

```
requestSent: boolean = false;

this.httpService.addNewAgent(object)
            .subscribe(
            data => {

                this.requestSent = false;


            },
            error => {

                console.log(error.error);

            }
            );
```

But this is rather long winded to do on every single component. Is there a more universal way of dealing with this? Perhaps with interceptors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @DmitriyKhirniy for the reply but I wanted a more universal way of disabling buttons during ajax requests. I found a way using directives, services and the interceptor. So using this you will only ever have to apply the attribute `disableDuringAjax` to your button(s).

Template:

```html
<button type="submit" disableDuringAjax>Sign In</button>
```

If you have a button that also disables due to form validation you could use:

```
<button type="submit" disableDuringAjax [formValid]="myForm">Sign In</button>
```

With the `[formValid]` simply mentioning the instance of the form in general, the directive will do rest of the work.

Directive (disable-button-during-ajax.directive.ts):

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, Directive, HostListener, HostBinding, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { BusyService } from '../../shared/services/busy.service';
import { Subscription, Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
    selector: '[disableDuringAjax]'
})

export class DisableButtonDuringAjax implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

    private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    @Input() formValid;
    
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private _busyService: BusyService, private el: ElementRef) {

        

    }




    checkFormValidation(form)
    {
        if ((form.valid == true)) {
            this.checkAjaxProgress();
        }
        if ((form.valid == false)) {
            this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
        }
    }


    checkAjaxProgress()
    {

        this.subscription = this._busyService.busy$
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(
            response => {




                if ((response == true)) {
                    this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
                }

                if ((response == false)) {
                    this.el.nativeElement.disabled = false;
                }

                // Check form one more time
                if ((this.formValid != null)) {
                    if ((this.formValid.valid == false)) {
                        this.el.nativeElement.disabled = true;
                    }
                }


            }
            );
    }



    doChecks()
    {
        // If there is no form to check validation then just check the ajax progress
        if ((this.formValid == null)) {
            this.checkAjaxProgress();
        }
        // Else check the forms validation AND ajax progress
        else {
            this.checkFormValidation(this.formValid);
            this.formValid.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(data => this.checkFormValidation(this.formValid));
        }
    }



    ngOnInit() {

        
        this.doChecks();
        

    }



    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges)
    {
        this.doChecks();
    }




    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next(null);
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }




}
```

Service (busy.service.ts):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class BusyService {

    numberOfBusyRequests: number = 0;
    numberOfNonBusyRequests: number = 0;

    // Observable navItem source
    private _busySource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
    // Observable navItem stream
    busy$ = this._busySource.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    changeBusy(val) {

        if ((val == true)) {
            this.numberOfBusyRequests = this.numberOfBusyRequests + 1;
        }
        else {
            this.numberOfNonBusyRequests = this.numberOfNonBusyRequests + 1;
        }

     


        if (this.numberOfBusyRequests == this.numberOfNonBusyRequests) {
            this._busySource.next(false);
        }
        else {
            this._busySource.next(true);
        }




    }
}
```

Interceptor (your own interceptor):

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import { BusyService } from './busy.service';

@Injectable()
export class ProgressInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private busyService: BusyService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(req).do(
            event => {


                // If request was sent
                if ((event.type == 0))
                {
                    this.busyService.changeBusy(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.busyService.changeBusy(false);
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Make sure to include the directive into your app.module or shared module.
And also make sure to include the service into your app.module.

**UPDATE June 2022 - I've created a library for this now = https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-disable-during-ajax**

Comment: my this.formValid.valueChanges come in undefined in the directive - why?

Comment: can you create a stackblitz for this example, would be really helpful. Ive implemented it but cant get it to work. The directive only runs when I land on the form and not on button click

Comment: @TomRudge sorry it's about 2 years too late, but here is the stackblitz :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1qkadm

Answer (score 3):

There are several cases to resolve this problem: 
First approach:

```
this.httpService.addNewAgent(object)
        .do(() => this.isLoading = true)
        .finally(() => this.isLoading = false)
        .subscribe()
```

Second approach is creating service with Subject:

```
 @Injectable()
 class LoadingService {
     isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviourSubject(false);
  }
```

In your intenceptor you will set sometihn like this:

```
  this.service.isLoading(currentState);
```

In your component:

```
this.service.isLoading.subscribe((state) => this.isLoading = state)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wanted a more universal way by just applying an attribute onto the button rather than still having to write logic in every single component. I've put my answer above. Many thanks again for taking the time to help me :)