# How to prevent double click in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-directive

I have a component with `click`.

```
<my-box (click)="openModal()"></my-box>
```

When I click this element, `openModal` function will run. 
And I'd like to give 1000ms throttle time in order to prevent opening multiple modals.

My first approach was using `Subject` (from rxJs)

```
//html
<my-box (click)="someSubject$.next()"></my-box>
//ts
public someSubject$:Subject<any> = new Subject();
...etc subscribe
```

But I feel it's a bit verbose.

Next Approach was using a `directive`.
I modified a bit of code that I found by googling.

```
//ts
import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[noDoubleClick]'
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective {

    constructor() {
    }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();    // not working as I expected.
        event.preventDefault();     // not working as I expected.

        event.srcElement.setAttribute('disabled', true);    // it won't be working unless the element is input.
        event.srcElement.setAttribute('style', 'pointer-events: none;');   // test if 'pointer-events: none' is working but seems not. 

        setTimeout(function () {
            event.srcElement.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }, 500);
    }
}

//html
<my-box noDoubleClick (click)="openModal()"></my-box>
```

However, whatever I try, always `openModal` was executed.
I couldn't find how to stop executing `openModal` in the directive.

I can just make like

```
//ts
//In the openModal method.
openModal() {
    public isClickable = true

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.newsClickable = true;
    }, 1000);
    ...
}
```

But for the reusable code, I think using directive is ideal.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use RxJs' [debounce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce) or [debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime) operator to prevent double clicks. [Here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-custom-debounce-click-directive-in-angular) is also a post on how to create a custom debounce click directive.

In case the post is taken down in the future, here is the final code:

#### Directive:

```js
import { 
  Directive, 
  EventEmitter, 
  HostListener, 
  Input, 
  OnDestroy, 
  OnInit, 
  Output 
} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDebounceClick]'
})
export class DebounceClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() 
  debounceTime = 500;

  @Output() 
  debounceClick = new EventEmitter();
  
  private clicks = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
      debounceTime(this.debounceTime)
    ).subscribe(e => this.debounceClick.emit(e));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

#### Example Usage:

```html
<button appDebounceClick (debounceClick)="log()" [debounceTime]="700">Debounced Click</button>
```

Comment: It works like a charm! I didn't think about Output in the directive.

Comment: Is it possible to use the original (click) attribute to reduce the number of new attributes created?

Comment: @sam-herrmann Is the event.stopPropagation() really needed? This will prevent any parent component from handling the click event. For example a global inactivity timer that listens to all click events

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you couldn't leave out event.stopPropagation(). But if I needed to propagate the event, I'm not sure if I'd dispatch the event within the subscribe after this.debounceClick.emit(e). I guess the question is, do you consider a click that's being debounced and therefore doesn't have an effect as an "activity"? If you consider all clicks an activity even if they don't make it past the debounceTime operator then you can probably just remove event.stopPropagation().

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but if we use a directive like this one say 100 buttons on an app, does this have a negative effect on performance? I can see all 100 buttons do their own subscribe and unsubscribe.

Answer (score 76):

Since some people asked for the `throttleTime` directive, I'll add it below. I chose to go this route because the `debounceTime` waits for the last click before firing the actual click event. `throttleTime` will not allow the clicker to click the button again until that time is reached and instead fires the click event immediately.

### Directive

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appPreventDoubleClick]'
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input()
  throttleTime = 500;

  @Output()
  throttledClick = new EventEmitter();

  private clicks = new Subject();
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.clicks.pipe(
      throttleTime(this.throttleTime)
    ).subscribe(e => this.emitThrottledClick(e));
  }

  emitThrottledClick(e) {
    this.throttledClick.emit(e);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks.next(event);
  }
}
```

### Example Usage

`throttleTime` is optional since there is a default of 500 in the directive

```html
<button appPreventDoubleClick (throttledClick)="log()" [throttleTime]="700">Throttled Click</button>
```

If you have a bot that's clicking on your element every 1ms, then you'll notice that the event only ever fires once until the `throttleTime` is up.

Comment: This is brilliant. You could also extend the directive with throttleTime `config` `{leading: false, trailing: true}` to only allow double clicking. By default it's `{ leading: true, trailing: false }`.

Comment: What is "log()" param? I tried change by event but dosen't works.

Comment: @MiguelNavas `throttleClick` is an event emitter. When that event is emitted, your component that theoretically would have a `log` function (taken directly from the accepted answer above) would be called. https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular
https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter
https://docs.angular.lat/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: This should be the way

Comment: How I can use conditional click event?

Answer (score 14):

In my case `throttleTime` instead of debounce was better solution(fire event immediately and block until some time passed)

Comment: What about posting an example code as given in the answer?

Answer (score 12):

I propose a simpler approach for buttons:

```js
    import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

    const DISABLE_TIME = 300;
    
    @Directive({
        selector: 'button[n-submit]'
    })
    export class DisableButtonOnSubmitDirective {
        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
        @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
        clickEvent() {
            this.elementRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
            setTimeout(() => this.elementRef?.nativeElement?.removeAttribute('disabled'), DISABLE_TIME);
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```html
    <button n-submit (click)="doSomething()"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Also would be great to care about the fact that element might be dstroyed during DISABLE_TIME. So might consider using safe construction like `this.elementRef?.nativeElement?.removeAttribute(…`

Answer (score 2):

Below code work for me to prevent double click.

```
onClick(event) {
    const button = (event.srcElement.disabled === undefined) ? event.srcElement.parentElement : event.srcElement;
        button.setAttribute('disabled', true);
        setTimeout(function () {
        button.removeAttribute('disabled');
        }, 1000);
    //Your code}
```

And HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-save" (click)="onClick($event)">
                        Prevent Double click
                    </button>
```

Comment: I used it for a non-button and this pattern works also there.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe want prevent many clicks on button? I'm using following solution:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[disableAfterClick]'
})
export class DisableButtonAfterClickDirective {
    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
    clickEvent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.currentTarget.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it is the most effective and elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a custom directive.

Put it somewhere in your template:

```
<button appSingleClick (singleClick)="log()" [throttleMillis]="1000">click</button>
```

The SingleClickDirective directive

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {throttleTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSingleClick]'
})
export class SingleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscription: Subscription;

  @Input()
  throttleMillis = 1500;

  @Output()
  singleClick = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(throttleTime(this.throttleMillis))
      .subscribe((v) => {
        this.singleClick.emit(v);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe();
    this.singleClick.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decide to combine great ideas from the people who replied above, also used more natural way to detect component destroying (`destroyed$ = new Subject()` ... using `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)` and `this.destroyed$.next()` in `ngOnDestroy`).

Also, used `throttleTime` and a special use case when an element is a button - in that case it also become disabled (for the same throttle time) and then enabled again. It does a check if button *was* already disabled - then do nothing with it (in terms of disabling). So you wound't encounter an issue when previously disabled button got enabled after click.

Another small detail is that directive selector is the same as output event name, it means that you can use it just with one attribute, not two, like this: `<div (appClickOnce)="myMethod()"></div>`

So, here is the full code, any questions/suggestions are welcome:

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { throttleTime, takeUntil, tap, map, switchMap, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appClickOnce]'
})
export class ClickOnceDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  @Input() clickLockTime = 500; // ms
  @Output() appClickOnce = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();
  
  private clicks$ = new Subject();
  private destroyed$ = new Subject();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.clicks$.pipe(
      throttleTime(this.clickLockTime),
      tap((event: MouseEvent) => this.appClickOnce.emit(event)),
      map(() => {
        if ((this.elementRef?.nativeElement as HTMLElement)?.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
          const button = this.elementRef?.nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement;
          if (button.disabled) {
            return false;
          }
          button.disabled = true;
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }),
      switchMap((needToEnableButton: boolean) => !needToEnableButton ? of() :
        timer(0).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            if (needToEnableButton && (this.elementRef?.nativeElement as HTMLElement)?.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
              (this.elementRef?.nativeElement as HTMLButtonElement).disabled = false;
            }
          })
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
    ).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next();
    this.destroyed$.complete();
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  clickEvent(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.clicks$.next(event);
  }

}
```

And exmamples of use:

```html
<div (appClickOnce)="myMethod()"></div>
```

```html
<div (appClickOnce)="myMethod()" [clickLockTime]="700"></div>
```

And when you use it in button, the button get disabled for small amount of time (for `clickLockTime` milliseconds):

```html
<button (appClickOnce)="myMethod()">Test me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**create a custom directive that disables the button after it has been clicked. This approach is more flexible, as it allows you to specify the amount of time that should elapse before the button is re-enabled.**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDisableButton]'
})
export class DisableButtonDirective {
  @Input() appDisableButton: number;
  private button: HTMLButtonElement;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.button = this.el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.button.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.button.disabled = false;
    }, this.appDisableButton);
  }
}
```

**You can then use this directive by adding the appDisableButton attribute to your button element and binding it to the amount of time (in milliseconds) that the button should be disabled. For example:**

```
<button appDisableButton="1000">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom Directive without "debounce" operator.

Template:

```
<button preventDoubleClick (сlick)="log()">click</button>
```

Directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {fromEvent, Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[preventDoubleClick]'
})
export class PreventDoubleClickDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private clickSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.clickSubscription.add(fromEvent(this.elementRef.nativeElement, 'click', {
      capture: true,
    }).pipe(
      tap((event: MouseEvent) => {
        if (event.detail > 1) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
      })
    ).subscribe());
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.clickSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```