# On button click, subscribe() is called twice sometimes

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a button on my html page, on clicking this button data is saved in the database. Sometimes, the same record is saved twice in the database, unable to debug the reason.

My code:

`home.html`

```
<button ion-button class="orng_btn" (click)="has_pass()" [disabled]="disabled_kot == true?true:false">Save</button>
```

`home.ts`

```
    has_pass()
    {
       this.disabled_kot = true;

    // calling webservice
    this.user.k_kot(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(this.f_arr))).subscribe(data=>{
    console.log(data,"data");
    this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
    });
    }
```

Note that on pressing the button we are using `setRoot` to refresh the page, is it that this sometimes may be creating 2 instances of this page? Or there is something else we need to do?

Comment: 1. Is there an error that causes the API to get called a second time. 2. Are you clicking it twice?

Comment: You could debounce the click event.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390476/how-to-prevent-double-click-in-angular

Comment: Also you could shorten "[disabled]="disabled_kot == true?true:false" to "[disabled]="disabled_kot" :)

Comment: @NicholasK no there is no error, it is just saved twice

Comment: @mbojko gone through the link, i think throttle time will be a better option to add, going to try with it

Comment: There are few posibilites here, is this button part of a form? if so, do you have a submit listener on that form? if yes, the function gets called from the button first time and from the submit callback second time.